# Display Flipkart listing on web site

Tags: python, marketplace, flipkart-api

I created a listing in Flipkart.
**Request URL:**

> https://sandbox-api.flipkart.net/sellers/skus/my-special-sku/listings
>
> Request:Method: POST
> Request:Payload:
> {"skuId": "my-special-sku", "attributeValues":
> {"national_shipping_charge": 20, "listing_status": "ACTIVE",
> "procurement_sla": 3, "mrp": 2400, "fulfilled_by": "seller",
> "zonal_shipping_charge": 20, "local_shipping_charge": 20,
> "selling_price": 2350, "stock_count": 23}, "fsn": "BZREBFVY8YQKXYFG"}

The Response is:

> {u'status': u'success', u'response': {u'status': u'updated', u'skuId': u'my-special-sku', u'errors': [], u'listingId': u'LSTBZREBFVY8YQKXYFGMF3BUG'}}

How can I view this listing on Flipkart site, or in my Flipkart account?

Comment: Hi mate, how did you get "fsn" ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are using is the seller-api on Sandbox.
Sandboxes are like playgrounds for your API integrations. You cannot access real production data from sandbox APIs. So you will not see the listing you have created.

You will be able to see your listing created in your 'seller-account for sandbox'. Not in your flipkart account.